# How do I do a MongoDb query that finds all key value pairs in a collection, where the Value is an array that has an element with a particular value

Tags: mongodb, find

If my collection is a set of  key values, with key name "k" and value name "v", and if each  value is a set of elements, and some of the elements with name "n" have value "1234", how can I write a MongoDb query to get all such key value pairs where "n" = "1234"?

Comment: can you add some sample document and expected outputs

Comment: Something like [this](https://mongoplayground.net/p/2TO8YAOOlTB)?